# Cordova sqlite plugin - Cannot read property ' item'

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am tying to make a simple query by ionic  i used sqlite plugin  ,  I tried several statement (insert,update,delete) all works fine .

But i get a problem with select statement

> Cannot read property 'item' of undefinedCannot read property 'item' of undefined

Note:  I have previously  created a table called cars with two columns type and year

Here's the full code

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);

app.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        if (cordova.platformId === "ios" && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

            // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
            // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
            // a much nicer keyboard experience.
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }


        // Select from table 


        var db = null;

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            //db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'demo.db', location: 'default' });
            db = window.openDatabase("localDB", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);

            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                var query = 'SELECT *  FROM cars';
                tx.executeSql(query, [], function (res)
                {
                    alert(res.rows.item(0).type);

                });
          
                
                

            })

        });




    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!--For users deploying their apps to Windows 8.1 or Android Gingerbread, platformOverrided.js
    will inject platform-specific code from the /merges folder -->
    <script src="js/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">SQLITE DATABASE </h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
  

      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx,res){
       alert(res.rows.item(0).type);
});
```

Comment: You are welcome! The first param of executeSql is an object you can execute some sqlite-statements on, as you have already on one step before. The second param holds the actual result of the statement. This is true when calling executeSql from a "tx"-object but when calling it from a "db"-object then the first param is the result of the query already, as you can see [here](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/blob/storage-master/README.md). Hope it helps! PS: Mark my answer as right, please ;)

Comment: PS: there are many db-plugins out there, whether executeSql works similar in every plugin can not be guaranteed.

Comment: The db-plugin above is very similar to the built-in sqlite-adapter you used nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks i got it , can you explain what's the difference between sqlite pulign that i used , and the  ngCordova sqlite  plugin .

Comment: The main difference between both plugins are the options you can pass. Although there is a physical limit about how much data you can store in a app, you are not restricted to a certain store-amount at the beginning with the built-in plugin (because you have to pass a number as last param), whereas you must not define a certain store-amount with this [plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/blob/storage-master/README.md). Furthermore this plugin prints out all transactions it made, so it's easier to get a clue where your app stopped due to an error while you are debugging